# Upper bound of Khintchine inequality

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove the upper bound for exercise 2.6.5 in the following notes:
[http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~liweiyu/documents/HDP-book.pdf](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eliweiyu/documents/HDP-book.pdf)

I need to show that:
$$
\| \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \|_{L^p} \leq C K \sqrt{p} \| a \|_{2}^2
$$

where $p \geq 2$, $X_i$ are independent sub-gaussian RV's with mean zero and unit variance, $C>0$ is an absolute constant and $K = \text{max}_{1 \leq i \leq n} ( \| X_i \|_{\psi_2} )$

So far I have that by using the General Hoeffing inequality that:

$$
\| \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \|_{L^p} = \int_{0}^{\infty} pt^{p-1} \mathbb{P}( \sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \geq t) \mathrm{d}t \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} 2 \text{exp}(-\frac{ct^2}{K^2 \|a\|_{2}^2}) pt^{p-1} \mathrm{d}t
$$

However I am unable to get anywhere in order for the final bound to pop out.

Comment: w.l.g assume $\|a\|^2_2=1$. Then you can proceed as in the classical Bernoulli case.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you also find it useful, could you please give me your upvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=\sum^N_{n=1}a_nX_n$ is such that $\sum^N_{k=1}a^2_n=1=\|S\|^2_2$. Let $\kappa^2:=c/K^2$.
For $p\geq2$
\begin{align}
\int |S|^p\,dP&=p\int^\infty_0 \lambda^{p-1}P[|S|>\lambda]\,d\lambda\\
&\leq 2p\int^\infty_0 \lambda^{p-1}e^{-(\kappa\lambda)^2/2}\,d\lambda\\
&=\frac{1}{\kappa^p}2p\int^\infty_0(2t)^{\tfrac{p-2}{2}}e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\kappa^p} 2^{p/2+1}\Gamma\big(p/2 +1\big)=:K^p_p
\end{align}
where we have used the change of variables $t=(\kappa\lambda)^2/2$. This shows that for any finite linear combination $X=\sum^n_{k=1}\alpha_nX_n$
$$\|X\|_p\leq K_p\|X\|_2$$
where $K_p=1$ for $0<p\leq 2$ and $K_p=\Big(\frac{1}{\kappa^p}2^{\tfrac{p}{2}+1}\Gamma(\tfrac{p}{2}+1)\Big)^{1/p}$ for $p>2$.

Comment: In your 4 line calculation, how did you go from the 3rd to the 4th line?

Comment: @660kaej: There is a  typo, the power of $(2t)$ should be $(p-2)/2$.

Comment: @660kaej: $t=\kappa^2\lambda^2/2$ so that $dt=\kappa^2\lambda\,d\lambda$
\begin{align}2p\int^\infty_0\lambda^{p-1}e^{-(\kappa\lambda)^2/2}\,d\lambda&=\frac{2p}{\kappa^2}\int^\infty_0(2t/\kappa^2)^{(p-2)/2}e^{-t}\,dt=\frac{2p}{\kappa^p}2^{p/2 -1}\int^\infty_0t^{p/2 -1}e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{2^{p/2+1}}{\kappa^p}\frac{p}{2}\Gamma\big(\tfrac{p}{2}\big)
\end{align}